# Graphql query way too slow with nested fields

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

So I'm using apollo-graphql,
I have a subgraph named Course, in this subgraph I have a type Course which looks like this:

```
type Course {
  _id: ID
  title: String
}
```

Now I have a second subgraph named progress, in this one I extend the Course type and add a field:

```
extend type Course @key(fields: "_id") {
  _id: ID @external
  totalProgression: Int
}
```

And now I want to query it like this:

```
Courses {
  _id
  title
  totalProgression
}
```

(Courses is a query which returns all courses)
This query works, but the problem is, it's way too slow. And that's because for each course, it is going to make a db request to get the totalProgression. If I add another nested field from another subgraph, it is going to take even longer.

My question here is, is there any way I could make this faster? For example could I make one db request to get all the totalProgression and then putting them in the courses? Without having to merge my subgraphs.

My only solution for now is to get the totalProgressions inside the Courses resolvers, but that would kill the point of making another subgraph. Yes I could juste merge all my subgraphes, but that's not how graphql is supposed to work.